# Can't connect to Samba Share on Linux File Server as a Guest user

Tags: network, macos, smb

I have a File Server (Linux, Mint) running Samba which allows Windows machines on the network to connect as a Guest and read / write files to the shared folder.

I have a Mac book running El Capitan. This is unable to connect to the server and on trying to do so gives the following error

```
There was a problem connecting to the server "192.168.0.7"
Check the server name or IP Address...
```

I have tried using all of the following connection strings

```
smb://192.168.0.7
smb://192.168.0.7/share
smb://user:password@192.168.0.7
smb://user:password@192.168.0.7/share

cifs://192.168.0.7
cifs://192.168.0.7/share
cifs://user:password@192.168.0.7
cifs://user:password@192.168.0.7/share
```

But without any success.

I can successfully connect using a username and password and am able to read/write but I am just unable to connect as a guest.

The windows (xp) machines on the network can connect as a guest and can read/write without any issues.

Comment: To separate network, OS and configuration problems, could you provide the output of: ••return••`ping 192.168.0.7`, `nmap 192.168.0.7`?

Comment: I agree with @danielAzuelos - first verify connectivity.  Once that's done and you know that your server can be reached, what does the Samba log say when you try to connect.  It should be located in `/usr/local/var/samba` directory

Comment: Sorry, yes I can ping and have since been able to connect as a registered user but am unable to connect as guest. nmap output :
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
902/tcp open  iss-realsecure

Comment: Argh, seems to be working fine now... not sure what I'd done wrong... will attempt to setup again from scratch to see if I can replicate the problem but many thanks for all your comments etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just to rule out the obvious. Are you able to ping those IPs? Maybe even nmap them to see if any ports might be closed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions.  Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions.  To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - From Review -